# Is it possible to combine talwind daisyUI with CSS variables?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Is it possible to combine tailwind daisyUI with CSS variables? like this? With DaisyUI

`:root { --primary-color:#570df8; }`

how to use something like this? which is not working,

````
  themes: [
      {
        mytheme: {
          primary: "var(--primary-color)", //not working
          "primary-focus": "#4506cb",
          "primary-content": "#ffffff",
          secondary: "#f000b8",
          "secondary-focus": "#bd0091",
          "secondary-content": "#ffffff",
        },
      },
    ],```
````

Answer (score -1):

You should put:

```
:root { --primary-color:#570df8; }
```

after your @tailwind directives in your main style file.

Comment: Hey look above I added it in my style,

this works at taiwind:


`module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary-color": "var(--primary-color)",
        "secondary-color": "var(--secondary-color)"
      },
    },
  },
};`




but it doesn't work with Tailwind, like the example I added